# How/where does pd.pivot_table store or reference the names of its index and column variables?

Tags: python, pandas, inheritance, dataframe, pivot-table

I can't figure out how pandas `pd.pivot_table` stores or references the ***names*** of the variables in the table's row/index and columns; from looking at the source code it doesn't seem to store them anywhere in any of its attributes, although `str(tbl)` obviously gets them from somewhere. Spent hours trying to figure it out and can't:

FYI The class hierarchy is: `pivot_table (tools/pivot.py)` is an instance of `class DataFrame (core/frame.py) which inherits from -> NDFrame (core/generic.py) -> PandasObject (core/base.py) -> StringMixin`. But after going through all that source, I don't see variable names stored anywhere in that hierarchy?!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2,2,3,2,3,1,3],
                   'bar': [8,6,8,7,7,6,6,7],
                   'baz': np.random.rand(8).round(2)})

tbl = df.pivot_table(values='baz', index='foo', columns='bar')

# where are the names 'foo', 'bar' stored inside the attributes of tbl?

# bar     6      7     8
# foo                   
# 1    0.39    NaN  0.97
# 2    0.76  0.240  0.97
# 3    0.18  0.245   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'foo' and 'bar' are stored as the names of the index and column index of `tbl` respectively. Index objects are distinct from DataFrame/NDFrame objects.

```
>>> tbl.index.name
'foo'
>>> tbl.columns.name
'bar'
```

The relevant part of the source code, where the `.name` attribute is set, is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/indexes/base.py#L146).